# how to get objects from a JSON array based on a key value pair inside the object in typescript without looping

Tags: json, typescript

Below is my JSON Array. I need to get the objects from the array which have objects with `key`:name and `value`:cricket.

Is there any way I can achieve this without using loops?

```
[
  {
 "name": "cricket",
 "ground": "JBL Ground",
 "capacity": "50000"
  },
{
 "name": "rugby",
 "ground": "IPL Ground",
 "capacity": "55000"
  },
{
 "name": "running",
 "ground": "PPL Ground",
 "capacity": "10000"
  },
{
 "name": "cricket",
 "ground": "MBL Ground",
 "capacity": "34000"
  },
{
 "name": "cricket",
 "ground": "KIG Ground",
 "capacity": "19000"
  }

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const allData = [
  {
 "name": "cricket",
 "ground": "JBL Ground",
 "capacity": "50000"
  },
{
 "name": "rugby",
 "ground": "IPL Ground",
 "capacity": "55000"
  },
{
 "name": "running",
 "ground": "PPL Ground",
 "capacity": "10000"
  },
{
 "name": "cricket",
 "ground": "MBL Ground",
 "capacity": "34000"
  },
{
 "name": "cricket",
 "ground": "KIG Ground",
 "capacity": "19000"
  }

]

const wantedData = allData.filter(item => item.name === 'cricket');

console.log(wantedData);
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20allData%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%22name%22%3A%20%22cricket%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22ground%22%3A%20%22JBL%20Ground%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22capacity%22%3A%20%2250000%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%22name%22%3A%20%22rugby%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22ground%22%3A%20%22IPL%20Ground%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22capacity%22%3A%20%2255000%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%22name%22%3A%20%22running%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22ground%22%3A%20%22PPL%20Ground%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22capacity%22%3A%20%2210000%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%22name%22%3A%20%22cricket%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22ground%22%3A%20%22MBL%20Ground%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22capacity%22%3A%20%2234000%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%22name%22%3A%20%22cricket%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22ground%22%3A%20%22KIG%20Ground%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22capacity%22%3A%20%2219000%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20wantedData%20%3D%20allData.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20item.name%20%3D%3D%3D%20'cricket')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(wantedData)%3B)